# Javascript check time difference

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript - check if time (Onclick) is more than 30sec.

I want to use it for connection timeout limit, if you know any other way please let me know.

How will I do that?

Comment: Yes, I know other ways.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Click on what? What is timing out?

Comment: okay i want a countdown t0 30 sec when a button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you want, but if you want to find out how long the button was pressed, there is how to do it.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var timeStamp = Date.now();

btn.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    timeStamp = Date.now();
});
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var t = Date.now() - timeStamp;
    /*You could add a condition to check the time here.*/
    document.getElementById('mssg').innerHTML = 
        "Mouse was hold " + t + " ms !";
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click and hold" />
<span id="mssg"></span>
```

Else, if you want to make something happend after a certain amount of time, here is how to do that :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = function(){
    alert('Hello !');
};
var remainingSeconds = 5;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    remainingSeconds--;
    if(remainingSeconds > 0){
        btn.value = 'Wait (' + remainingSeconds + ' sec left)';
    }
    else{
        clearInterval(interval);
        btn.disabled = false;
        btn.value = 'You can now click';
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Wait" disabled>
```

I hope, I could help ! Please be more precise in your questions in the future !

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? Hope this helps you out <3

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert('Hello');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click "Try it". Wait 3 seconds, and the page will alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```